# Python virtual environment package install issue

Tags: python, django, pip, easy-install

I'm building a Python project requiring Django.  I have created a project directory and virtual environment using virtualenv.  But I can't install django using PIP and I have to use easy_install in order to install it into the virtual environment.

Note - I only have this problem with Django.  I am able to successfully install other packages into the virtual environment using PIP without issues.

I'm running the following sequence...

```
cd projectfolder
virtualenv venv
venv\Scripts\activate
pip install django
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access 
is denied: 'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-unpack- 
kc0_p8wh\\Django-2.1-py3-none-any.whl'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Again - if I run the same block of code, but end it with:

```
easy_install django
```

Then the package installs fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: For whatever reason running the `pip.cmd` (i.e. `pip`) on Windows results in a lower privilege as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172719/pip-install-access-denied-on-windows), so the workaround is to use `python -m pip` instead (i.e. try `python -m pip install django`).

Comment: Thanks.  But this still doesn't work.  I get the same error message listed below.  And it's only for this 1 package (Django).  I'm able to install other packages without issue.  But for some reason, it only brings this error up when install Django.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Just a followup: looks pretty similar to [this question that has no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517742/django-wont-install-on-windows-using-pip).  Might be a bug with the wheel provided by django when interacted through Windows.

Comment: It looks as if PIP unpacks to the temp directory - and for whatever reason - can't find the package in the temporary once it unpacks it.  I'm totally clueless as to what this could mean.

Answer (score 1):

In most situations the best solution is to rely on the so-called "user site" location by running:

pip install --user package_name

If that doesn't work, you need the admin rights.
So just run the cmd as an administrator.

Or better yet create a virtualenv and then install. Instructions can be found on:
https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Comment: I have admin rights and am still getting this error, whether I'm in the virtual environment or not.  And it's ONLY with this package (Django).  I don't have any issues installing any other packages in or out of the virtualenv.  Only Django causes problems.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually active your virtual-env, and your error information show as:

> C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack- 
>   kc0_p8wh\Django-2.1-py3-none-any.whl

Nothing about `venv/xxx/path`, so you should active by.

*FOR Linux*

`source venv\Scripts\activate` first. and then try install again.

*FOR WIN*
Thanks for @metatoaster remind at the comments below.
But it depends on where are you `virtualenv` path.

`C:\Venv\Scripts>activate`

To make sure whether you are in virtual-env , just check whether you have a special subfix at the begin of command line. something like:

```
(my_venv)landpacks
```

Comment: `source` is part of `bash`, not `cmd` on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, but this still didn't work.  For some reason, the only package that gives me a problem is Django (both inside and outside of the virtualenv).  I can install any other package fine, but this is the only one that causes problems.

Comment: And I can still install Django using easy_install.  Just not PIP.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems your `pip` has no privilege to do this operations. and can you switch to super user (something like linux root user).