# Upgrade pip from 10 to 18

Tags: python-3.x, pip, upgrade

I am trying to install the [robotframework](http://robotframework.org/).

I am on a windows machine and on the command line I entered:

```
pip install robotframework
```

But pip asks me to upgrade pip from 10 to 18, so I use this command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

This resulted in an error message:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5]
Accès refusé : `c:\\program files (x86)\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-10.0.1.dist-inf o\\entry_points.txt`
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmd pip displaying errors whenever I try to install pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138069/cmd-pip-displaying-errors-whenever-i-try-to-install-pygame)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+EnvironmentError+WinError+5

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 64 bit version of python I guess this will work for you:

Try opening the command prompt with administrator privileges and update pip from here.

Comment: The problem is solved I used this comand line /python -m pip install --user  --upgrade pip/ and re install the correct python package for 64bit like you suggest thanks