# i can't install numpy in win 10

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip

when I install numpy (pip install numpy) with CMD I encounter with this error!

My win is 10. version of pyyhon is 3.7.3

```
pip install numpy

C:\Users\Hamed>pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/9d/c129d78e6b942303b762ccfdf1f8339de80c5e6021b14ef0c99ec5bdc6aa/numpy-1.16.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmd pip displaying errors whenever I try to install pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138069/cmd-pip-displaying-errors-whenever-i-try-to-install-pygame)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+EnvironmentError%3A+WinError+5+Access+is+denied

Comment: Either open a cmd line with Adminstrator permissions, or use Python virtual environments, or run `pip install --user`.

Answer (score 1):

Try running cmd as administrator